# Как закрасить страну определнным цветом и сохранить как изображение для редактирования?

Tags: google-maps-api

Я [кое-что похожее](https://habrahabr.ru/post/197448/) нашел в нете.

Но не уверен что оно сделает точно как я хотел. Подскажите если это то что нужно. Предвижу много вопросов от меня к вам...

Comment: Можно просто поискать в интернете контуры такой-то страны, например контуры Индии - https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=контуры%20индии&noreask=1&lr=10750 и реально из фотографий есть рабочие варианты

Comment: Есть только один способ понять сделает или не сделает: попробовать.